# Load new remote content into an open modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3, any idea how I can load different remote content into a modal window that is already open? Basically, the modal window is open with remote content, the user clicks a button. instead of showing a new modal window, the current modal window is refreshed with the new content. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same way you'd do it without Bootstrap. Listen for the `click` event on the button, initiate an AJAX request, and then in the request's callback, load the DOM from the request into the relevant parts of the modal. [Bootstrap's built-in remote modal feature is deprecated anyways.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034)

Comment: Try AJAX request on button click.